# How to render slice of children in React with TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

A little background: I want to create a combination carousel with pagination in ReactJS.

I have code like this:

```js
interface HTMLCarouselT {
  children: Array<JSX.Element>
  size: number;
}

const HTMLCarousel = ({children, size}: HTMLCarouselT) => {
  const length = Math.ceil(size / children.length);
  const {
    step,
    isFirst,
    isLast,
    next: nextPage,
    prev: prevPage
  } = useStepper(length);
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        {children.slice(step * size, size).map((Item, index) => (
          <Item key={index}/>
        ))}
      </div>
      ...
    </div>
  )
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <HTMLCarousel size={3}>
      <h1>One</h1>
      <h1>Two</h1>
      <h1>Three</h1>
      <h1>Four</h1>
      <h1>Five</h1>
      <h1>Six</h1>
    </HTMLCarousel>
  );
}
```

But I got an error from TypeScript:

> JSX element type 'Item' does not have any construct or call signatures.

And runtime error:

> Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: `<h1 />`. Did you accidentally export a JSX literal instead of a component?

What is the proper way to display slices of children in ReactJS and TypeScript?
I want my component to be universal to work with components and elements.

Answer (score 1):

In the `map` of `HTMLCarousel` you have referred to the current element as `Item`.
And in JSX, you have referred to `<Item>`. It causes React to search for a component named `Item`. Even if `Item` exists will be ignored due the current element variable also being `Item`.

TLDR: Only class names & component names should begin with a capital letter.

Now to render children inside a map, just do

```
{ children.slice(step * size, size) }
```

This should work. If not replace `<Item>` with `<>` (React Fragment).

Comment: But he meant to use that param as a component. It is possible in a normal case.

Comment: Yes, an Item is not a component it's my parameter I don't have a component named Item I want to use an element from map not a separated component, that would be kind of silly.

Comment: But this answer is indeed working.

Comment: `{children.slice(step * size, size).map((Item, index) => ( <Item.type key={index}/> ))}` -  this will work, but I'm not sure about typescript